# Javascript - Largest prime factor of a number

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing the Project Euler challenges using javascript.
I'm doing the third challenge which involves finding the largest prime factor of a number, and my code works according to the example, but when I try to do a much larger number, the code ends up freezing?

```
//Functions
function PrimeChecker(Number){
//Variables
var Counter = 2;
//Check Number
    do{
        if(Number % Counter == 0){
                if(Counter == Number){
                    return true;
                    break;
                }
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else{
            Counter++;  
        }
    }while(Counter != Number+1);
}

function FactorChecker(Number){
//Variables
var Counter = Number;
//Check Prime
do{
    console.log("Count: "+Counter);
    if(Counter==Number){
        //Nothing
    }else{
            if(PrimeChecker(Counter) == true){
                if(Number%Counter==0){
                    console.log("Pass with: "+Counter);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Undivisable with: "+Counter);
                }
            }
        }
    Counter--;
    }while(true);
}

//End
FactorChecker(600851475143);
```

Before it crashes, the final output that it gives is `Count: 600851475067`

Comment: Number factorization is an np problem...if you find a quick algorithm there might be a noble prize in it for you

Comment: Well you are starting a bit high, it's really enough to go at max to the square root of the number you are checking (both to find the factor and to check for primes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple points on how you can optimize:

1. You do not need to iterate your loop all the way to Number. E.g. If `n = 10`, there is not need to check for numbers greater than 5.

This will reduce your computational time to half if you end your loop when `Counter > Number/2`

2. It can be optimized further. You stop the loop even earlier than at n/2. Find square root of Number (let's call it `sqrt_n`). Iterate from k = 2, 3, 4 ... sqrt_n and you should be good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another thing to note, that he shouldn't call `PrimeChecker` first, as it is an expensive operation, it might be even better to first check if the rest after division = 0 before checking if the `Counter` is a prime

Answer (score 0):

[Avi Dubey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729887/3231537) answer gives you already some great pointers in how to optimize your prime checking and factor checking, so this answer only shows you a suggestion how to rewrite your code.

I only would suggest that you first check if the number is dividable by your `Counter` before starting the prime checking, as checking for primes is more expensive that the modulo trick.

```js
function isPrime( number ) {
  const max = Math.ceil( Math.sqrt(number) );
  for (let i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function findLargestFactor( number ) {
  let counter = Math.ceil( number / 2 );
  do {
    if ( number % counter === 0 && isPrime( counter ) ) {
      break;
    }
  } while (--counter > 1);
  return counter === 1 ? 'none found' : counter;
}

console.log( isPrime(3) );
console.log( isPrime(5) );
console.log( isPrime(7) );
console.log( isPrime(11) );
console.log( isPrime(13) );
console.log( isPrime(17) );
console.log( isPrime( 600851475143 ) );

console.log( findLargestFactor( 15 ) );
console.log( findLargestFactor( 14 ) );
// this will still block (it is a huge number you are trying to compute)
//console.log( findLargestFactor( 600851475143 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take the smallest prime factor 2 and divide the number with it.
- If reminder is 0, then divisible by that prime number,  keep the loop going

```js
(function(n) {
  let i = 2
  while (i <= n) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      n /= i
    } else {
      i++
    }
  }
  return console.log(i)
})(10)
```